# System.Diagnostics.Process works on one pc but it doesn't work with the other ones

Tags: c#, cmd, visual-studio-2015

I'm using c# visual studio 2015 , I've tried to change the IP as administrator , I have the local administrator password for the PC so I've tried this code , It works properly on my PC.

the problem is that when I got the .exe file from the solution --> bin , then tried to use it on another PC it doesn't work although the local admin password is the same.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    string sysAdminUser = "test1";
    string sysAdminPass = "test2";

            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            System.Security.SecureString ssPwd = new System.Security.SecureString();
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"cmd.exe";
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c netsh interface ip set address \"Ethernet\" static 192.168.1.200 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.1";
            proc.StartInfo.Domain = "";
            proc.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            proc.StartInfo.UserName = sysAdminUser;
            string password = sysAdminPass;
            for (int x = 0; x < password.Length; x++)
            {
                ssPwd.AppendChar(password[x]);
            }
            password = "";
            proc.StartInfo.Password = ssPwd;
            proc.Start();    

    }
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "it doesn't work"? What *exactly* happens? Is an exception thrown, for example? (Please edit this information into the question.)

Comment: Nothing happen , It looks like that the cmd appears for seconds and hidden again without changing anything

Comment: @Peter the problem is using `cmd` in the first place. `cmd` opens a console window, it's not needed to run another program. Use just `netsh` as the `FileName` and `interface ip set addres ... ` as the `Arguments`

Comment: As I said before, please *edit that information into the question*. Additionally, I'd suggest adding information about what happens when you try to run the same process manually on the failing machine.

Comment: like Access denied

Comment: when I try to use it manually it works properly with both PCs

Comment: The `Verb` won't work though - that's for invoking *shell* commands like `Open` and `Print` on documents. If you want to run `netsh` using a different account, the `Verb` doesn't matter and the `Domain` is required if you use a domain account. I suspect the code throws an error which is lost because `cmd` exits immediatelly

Comment: `Access Denied` means that the user that tried to execute this code *doesn't* have permission to do so, or that UAC prevented a privileged operation. Starting a process using different credentials is such an operation. Without UAC, any malware could make modifications without anyone noticing

Comment: I'm using a domain account , but tried to remove the " Verb " line but it doesn't work.

Comment: You don't need to run `netsh` to modify the network anyway. You can use the classes in the `System.Management` namespace to modify network settings through WMI, on the local or remote machines, or over an entire network.

Comment: @Peter it doesn't work because UAC prevents this. You shouldn't be doing this in the first place, storing or passing an administrator's credentials like this *breaks* security. Windows already knows if the user has permission to change network settings or not. What you're trying to do is a pretty serious security breach

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206973/discussion-between-peter-and-panagiotis-kanavos).